# How can disable function wp_link_dialog()

Tags: theme-development

How can disable public static function wp_link_dialog from my theme function.php

in class-wp-editor.

I can delete it but if WordPress release any updates it will return to default again.

Answer (score -1):

You should make a child theme and include a definition in `functions.php` for the function that does nothing.

You should be able to find tutorials on making child themes with any google search.

Comment: This is very vague. Please add at least a code example for the specific problem.

Comment: I know that I must do that but I don't know what's to written inside functions.php that's my question.